# Making a Shortcut for Running Python Files in a Folder with CMD.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd

To run Python files (.py) with Windows CMD.exe, I SHIFT + Right Click on my project folder which contains all of my Python code files. Doing this shows a menu containing the option `Open command window here`, which I click to open CMD.exe with the prompt `C:\Users\Name\FolderLocation\ProjectFolder>`. I then type the python command, and the file I want to run in my project folder (`python MyFile.py`) which runs the file, of course.

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can setup a shortcut to open CMD.exe with my project folder opened/ being accessed so then all I have to do is type python and the file name? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe.

Get properties on that shortcut, and there's an entry for the current working directory. (They change the name of that field every other version of Windows, but I believe most recently it's called "Start In:".) Just set that to `C:\Users\Name\FolderLocation\ProjectFolder`.

Now, when you double-click that shortcut, it'll open a cmd.exe window, in your project directory.

Comment: I've done exactly what you've typed, but when I run the shortcut, the command prompt is `C:\Python33\`; the directory I selected to be opened when cmd.exe runs using the `PATH` variable. As expected, when I type the python command in with a file name, it returns and Error No. 2. I'm guessing if it works correctly that the prompt should be `C:\Users\Name\FolderLocation\ProjectFolder`. Please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what version of Windows you're on, or what the Shortcut properties look like for that version. And I have no idea where `C:\Python33` could have come from if you didn't type it (it's not the location of `cmd.exe`). Figuring out how to set the properties is really more of a SuperUser question than a StackOverflow question, but if you google-images "shortcut properties Windows 7" or whatever version is appropriate, the first few links should be about 50% examples of what you need to do. (The rest will mostly be about keyboard shortcuts in other preferences.)